# Why does my getParentNode function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, dom

I write a function, named getParentNode, that use to get some specific parentNode filtered by tagName. The code is as follow. I don't understand Why the function returns "undefined". I think it should return the specific parentNode or null. orz!
The code is also at http://jsfiddle.net/52ed6/2/

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <span id="reply">Reply</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <script>
        // Get specific parentNode
        function getParentNode(obj, selector){
            if (obj.parentNode) {
                if ( obj.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() === selector ) {
                    return obj.parentNode;
                } else {
                    getParentNode(obj.parentNode, selector);
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        var reply = document.getElementById('reply');
        // The function getParentNode() novalid
        // The next statement popup "undefined", why?
        alert(getParentNode(reply, 'li'))
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inside the first else use: **return** getParentNode(obj.parentNode, selector);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that you need to change this:

```
} else {
    getParentNode(obj.parentNode, selector);
}
```

to:

```
} else {
    return getParentNode(obj.parentNode, selector);
}
```

Without the `return` your function will execute and then not return any value to the original caller. You need the `return` to make this work recursively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess that the function without the "return" will return some value to other space.

Answer (score 1):

```
getParentNode(obj.parentNode, selector);
```

needs a `return`.

```
return getParentNode(obj.parentNode, selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

This specific block bypasses any return statements.  Therefore, it implicitly returns without any defined value, thus, undefined.

```
            } else {
                getParentNode(obj.parentNode, selector);
            }
```

You probably want

```
            } else {
                return getParentNode(obj.parentNode, selector);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `return`: http://jsfiddle.net/52ed6/5/

```
return getParentNode(obj.parentNode, selector);
```